# How to use tolower function for non-ascii characters

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I am trying to apply lower function on non-ASCII characters. Following code doesn't work in Linux(Ubuntu) environment but works in windows.

```
int main() {
        std:string data="ŽŠ";
        std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), ::tolower);
        cout<< data << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

I tried installing language packs but did not work.Can someone help me what am i missing in this code?

Comment: Have you tryed locale changing?

Comment: It isn't a good idea to create string literals using non-ASCII characters and have these strings in the source file.   Create literals using the correct escape sequences that represent the string.

Answer (score 5):

`::tolower()` relies in the current locale set in the C library.  The default `"C"` locale is only guaranteed to handle ASCII characters.  Microsoft is likely using a different default locale that matches the user's current locale.  That would explain why the code is able to work on Windows.

Use [`::setlocale()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale) to set the desired locale for `::tolower()` to use.  Otherwise, use a portable Unicode library, such as [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org).

Comment: As the string is written directly in the .cpp file - could the issue be related to an encoding mismatch between file's one and expected one of compiler, too?

Comment: @Aconcagua: yes, that is also an issue to watch out for when using narrow strings.

Comment: I tried setting locale `std::setlocale(LC_ALL,"de_DE");` and used "cin" rather than writing directly in file but still doesn't work. My OS locale was "en_US" in both linux and windows.

Comment: `setlocale()` only affects C functions, not STL classes. `std::cin`, `std::cout`, and other STL streams have their own locale handling.  See the [`std::locale`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) class and the  [`std::basic_ios::imbue()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/imbue) method.